# Filter an array for valid content

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have an array like this:

```
$content_array = [
    "&nbsp;",
    "<p>",
    " ",
    "</p>",
    "<p>",
    "</p>",
    'mycontent',
    '<img src="some-image.jpg">',
    "",
    '&nbsp;',
    'some other content',
    '<div class="1">',
    '<div class="child">',
    ' ',
    '<b>',
    'content text',
    'my other content',
    '     ',
    ' '
];
```

And I need to return an array like this:

```
$content_array = [
    "<p></p><p></p>mycontent",
    '<img src="some-image.jpg">some other content',
    '<div class="1"><div class="child"><b>content text',
    'my other content',
];
```

So my plan is to get rid of "not printable" content, and consolidate HTML tags with text, if text is available, then it should jump to the next key. This is the code I have:

```
$content_array = [
    "&nbsp;",
    "<p>",
    " ",
    "</p>",
    "<p>",
    "</p>",
    'mycontent',
    '<img src="some-image.jpg">',
    "",
    '&nbsp;',
    'some other content',
    '<div class="1">',
    '<div class="child">',
    ' ',
    '<b>',
    'content text',
    'my other content',
    '     ',
    ' '
];

$the_fixed_array = fix_content($content_array);

function fix_content($content_array)
{
    $fixed_content_array = array();

    foreach ($content_array as $this_content) {

        $clean_content = preg_replace( '@([^[:print:]]|&nbsp;|\s+)@', '',$this_content);
        if (!$clean_content) continue;
        $has_text = strip_tags($clean_content);

        if ($has_text) {
            $fixed_content_array[] = $this_content;
            continue;
        }

        $where_to = count($fixed_content_array) ? count($fixed_content_array) - 1 : 0;

        if (!$where_to) {
            $fixed_content_array[$where_to] = $this_content;
            continue;
        }

        $fixed_content_array[$where_to] = $fixed_content_array[$where_to] . $this_content;
        $fixed_content_array = fix_content($fixed_content_array);
    }

    return $fixed_content_array;
}

print_r($the_fixed_array);
```

But it's failing, I got this:

```
(
    [0] => </p>
    [1] => mycontent<img src="some-image.jpg">
    [2] => some other content<div class="1"><div class="child"><b>
    [3] => content text
    [4] => my other content
)
```

I bet there's an easy way, could someone help me to accomplish this?

**SOLVED WITH**

```
function fix_content($content_array)
{
    $fixed_content_array = array();

    foreach ($content_array as $key => $this_content) {

        $where_to = count($fixed_content_array) ? count($fixed_content_array) - 1 : 0;
        $previous_element_has_content = strip_tags($fixed_content_array[$where_to]);

        $clean_content = preg_replace( '@([^[:print:]]|&nbsp;|\s+)@', '',$this_content);
        if (!$clean_content) continue;
        $has_text = strip_tags($clean_content);

        if ($has_text) {
            //Check if previous element has just html tags:
            if ($where_to || $where_to === 0) {

                if (!$previous_element_has_content) {
                    $fixed_content_array[$where_to] = $fixed_content_array[$where_to] . $this_content;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            $fixed_content_array[] = $this_content;
            continue;
        }

        if ($previous_element_has_content) {
            $fixed_content_array[] = $this_content;
            continue;
        }

        $fixed_content_array[$where_to] = $fixed_content_array[$where_to] . $this_content;
    }

    return $fixed_content_array;
}

print_r($the_fixed_array);
```

But I like @Oli's answer. But by looking at the result, I noticed that I actually needed something like:

```
[0] => <p></p><p></p>mycontent<imgsrc="some-image.jpg"><span>
[1] => someothercontent<divclass="1"><divclass="child"><b>
[2] => contenttext
[3] => myothercontent
```

It has to jump to the next key, only when *Text* is found. I appreciate your help!

Comment: why don't you just "chunk" your array into equal parts ?

Comment: What I want to achieve with this is to be able to separate content into paragraphs, and I don't want html tags, spaces or non-printable content to be taken as a paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way is similar to yours, I have a $tmpString to accumulate the string if a tag is found:

```
$result_array =[];
$tmpString = '';

foreach($content_array as $value) {
    $value = preg_replace('/(\s+?|(\&nbsp;))/', '', $value);

    if(!empty($value)) {
        preg_match('/(<.+?>)/', $value, $matches);

        if(isset($matches[1])) {
             $tmpString .= $matches[1];
        } else {
            $result_array[] = $tmpString. $value;
            $tmpString = '';
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result_array);
```

Comment: Nice, I like this answer, it matches what I was looking for, but I ended up needing something different, I've updated the question a bit, I'm working with your code, lets see if I can get the right result :) thanks Oli!

Answer (score 0):

Create another array with allowed characters and then using `in_array()` check if it allowed in your code.

A simple example:

```
$final_array = array();
$allowed_chars = array('<p>', '</p>');

foreach ($content_array as $v)
{
  if (in_array($v, $allowed_chars))
  {
    array_push($final_array, $v);
  }
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Comment: Hi there! The thing is that, any html tag is allowed.